# Дополнительная функция кнопке "Отправить"

Tags: html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в html сделать так:
существует кнопка `<input type="submit" name="submit1" class="btn" value="Next step">`, при нажатии отправляются данные из формы.
Что дописать, чтобы при нажатии и форма отправлялась, и открывалась определенная ссылка допустим в новом окне, например `https://ru.stackoverflow.com`, через `<a href=""` или как?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно через onClick попробовать:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit1" class="btn" value="Next step" onClick="window.open('https://ru.stackoverflow.com')">
```